# How to toggle multiple interleaving parts of the document on or off?

Tags: article, exsheets, answers

Suppose I want to design a document in the form:

```
Q1: What's the Color of The Ocean

A1: Blue

Q2: What is the Color of The Wind

A2: White
```

If I were to print out the PDF generated by this latex document, but without the answers, then I have to manually comment out each answer %.

Imagine there are hundreds of Q & A, then this becomes infeasible.

Is there a way to design this document so that all the answers can be toggled ON and OFF.

Ideally, something like this:

```
Let Flag = False

Q1: What's the Color of The Ocean

If Flag = True, Then{ A1: Blue}

Q2: What is the Color of The Wind

If Flag = True, Then{ A2: White}
```

and just change the flag from true to false and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you can create a toggle and then just toggle it on/off

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtoggle{printAnswers}
\newcommand{\showAnswers}{\toggletrue{printAnswers}}
\newcommand{\hideAnswers}{\togglefalse{printAnswers}}

%You can modify this however you want to change how the answer pieces are displayed
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{
    \iftoggle{printAnswers}{
         \par\textcolor{blue}{#1}
    }{}
}
%Change this to \hideAnswers
\showAnswers
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is a question
        \answer{This is an answer to the question}
        \item Another question
        \answer{Another answer}
    \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

I have a larger version of this code to change the spacing when the answer is shown vs. not that I'm happy to share if you want.

**Without Answers**
[image]

**With Answers**

[image]